# open program in user display from console

Tags: linux, xorg

I can't figure out .. 
I exported DISPLAY variable, but that don't work.

I have computer with ubuntu 11.10 on it. Computer have display. On display i am showing pictures in slideshow. So i connect via scp to computer and copy new pictures or delete some pics via cron job. I want to restart slideshow. 
Basically i need to run program from console in display.

Maybe i can run it via cron job ... ?
Thanks.

Comment: The DISPLAY variable should work, as long as the user has the right permissions.  Please give more details as to what happens when it "doesn't work" (errors messages?).

Comment: `export | grep DISPLAY
declare -x DISPLAY=":0.0"

gnome-terminal
No protocol specified
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1695924) discussion, I'm guessing that your hostname doesn't match the permissions controlled by xhost.  as a test, try `sudo xhost +` then launch your program to see if this is the right track.  If so, you'll have to decide if you want to leave access control off or if you want to play with xhost to fine tune it.

It could be that ssh'ing from another computer is influencing the hostname xhost is checking, so if you set up xhost correctly you may need to add your ssh client's IP address.